Why does the size of a struct change depending on whether an initial value is used?
In the following code, both D1 & D2 have the same data members.  However, the object size is different depending on whether the last member of the base class is initialized.
    #include <cstdint>
    
    struct B1 { int x; short y = 0; };
    struct D1 : B1 { short z; };
    struct B2 { int x; short y; };
    struct D2 : B2 { short z; };
    static_assert(sizeof(D1) == sizeof(D2));

GCC 14.2 (and Clang 18.0.1) fails with:
    <source>:7:26: error: static assertion failed
        7 | static_assert(sizeof(D1) == sizeof(D2));
          |               ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
    <source>:7:26: note: the comparison reduces to '(8 == 12)'

What is the explanation for this behavior?

The class layout used by GCC and Clang (in normal mode) is specified by the Itanium C++ ABI: https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html#class-types It's rather dense, though, and I'm not wading through it. They key difference is probably that B2 is a POD, while B1 is not.

static_assert passes if everything in B2 is marked private.  This is a fun puzzle.

Curious!  B2 is standard layout and trivial.  B1 is standard layout and non-trivial.  D2 is non-standard layout and trivial.  D1 is non-standard layout and non-trivial.

This is an arbitrary ABI choice for compatibility with C.
In the Itanium C++ ABI, as implemented by GCC and Clang here, B2 is considered POD for the purpose of layout while B1 is not. (It is reasonable because B2's definition is valid C as well, while B1's definition is not.)
The ABI specifies that tail padding of a type will be reused only if it is not POD for the purpose of layout. This assures that e.g. memcpy/memset as typically used in C is safe on the base class subobject and won't overwrite any derived class members. Also, in C the compiler is always allowed to overwrite padding if a member is modified and the C compiler is not aware of tail padding reuse. So even without calls to memcpy, etc. using the base class subobject in C would otherwise not be compatible with C++.
Both B1 and B2 have two bytes tail padding. D1 will reuse it to fit the z member, while D2 will not and leave the two padding bytes empty instead. Because the size of the whole class must be a multiple of its alignment which is 4 because of the int member, D2 then also needs to add two additional new tail padding bytes.

Or to be more precise:
It seems to me that the Itanium ABI does not clearly specify whether the default member initializer makes the type not POD for the purpose of layout. It uses the C++03 definition of POD which obviously is not aware of default member initializers which were introduced with C++11. However, it seems that GCC and Clang at least agreed that a default member initializer should make the class not POD for the purpose of layout and generally it makes sense that later language extensions of C++ should not need to worry much about C compatibility. (One could argue either direction, but at least a definition with a default member initializer can't be used in C unmodified.)

Also important:
GCC did not behave in this way for a while in C++14 or later mode. Before GCC 12, it did consider both types to be POD for the purpose of layout when compiling for C++14 or later. See the breaking ABI change version 17 at https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html. Clang seems to always have behaved as both do now.

Also note that this really is just an implementation choice (although one relevant to ABI and C compatibility). According to the C++ standard, using functions like memcpy/memset/etc. on a base class subobject has always undefined behavior, regardless of whether the types are POD/trivial in any capacity.

I'm not sure why does this change things. Neither D1 nor D2 is valid C struct, so could it not reuse the padding anyway? Or B2 being POD means "thou shalt not reuse padding under any circumstances"?

@Yksisarvinen With this specification you can safely create a D2 object and pass it as B2* to a C function that might overwrite its padding. (Not only via memcpy/memset btw. In C the compiler is always allowed to overwrite padding with any modification of a member.) But for D1/B1 that is not a concern because the definition of B1 can't even be parsed in C.

@Yksisarvinen, but B2 is a valid C struct.  If sizeof(D2) == 8, then memcpy/memset on B2 would overwrite the derived class members, even though D2 itself couldn't be used in C code.

@MarkB • D2's members are not "packed" into the padding of the B2.  If a C routine was memset'ing more than the sizeof(B2), it's doing something naughty.

A default initializer makes the class non-trivial and IIRC only trivial types can be POD types.

@NathanOliver Yes, but that is the C++11 definition. The Itanium ABI specifically refers ot the C++03 definition, because the definition changed in later C++ revisions. But the ABI ought to not change for types that were valid already in earlier revisions. Otherwise you couldn't link C++ code compiled in C++03 mode with code compiled in C++11 mode.

In C as invented by Dennis Ritchie, someStruct.member was equivalent to *(memberType)((char*)&someStruct+offsetof(structType,member), and most implementations worked that way.  Some implementations for platforms where e.g. a 32-bit write would be faster than a 16-bit write, however, would generate code that would sometimes disturb storage following a struct member that written.  The Standard wasn't intended to disturb the status quo where implementations would behave as implied by Dennis Ritchie's language absent a good reason for doing otherwise.

It makes sense that having a default member initializer would be considered the same as having a constructor, for the purpose of determining POD-ness (since that's what it does in the absence of optimizations).

@user20574 Both B1 and B2 have default constructors. The difference is only that the one of B1 is non-trivial. Both are also aggregate, trivially-copyable and implicit-lifetime types, which arguably means that it could make sense to use B1 from C: You would define it without the default member initializer in C and then the behavior would be completely compatible with and the same as in C++, except that a variable definition struct B1 b; would leave the member uninitialized in C and initialize it in C++. But the GCC/Clang ABI decides against this.

@user20574 And if the default member initializer didn't initialize to 0, then there would also be a difference in aggregate initialization with struct B1 b = {0}; on the C and C++ side. But in any case, the difference is always local to the initialization that isn't relevant cross-TU. But I can see that one wouldn't want to support these constructs.
